# Get the count of tables embedded in the PDF

Tags: r, tidyverse

Following code extracts the tables from PDF.

```
install.packages("tabulizer"); install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tabulizer); library(tidyverse)

n_tables <- extract_tables("filename.pdf") %>% length()
```

However, it takes forever to do this. Can we bypass the actual table extraction step, presumably a very time consuming process, and get the count of tables from pdfs directly using tabulizer or any other R package?

Answer (score 0):

Original tabulizer developer here: Nope. The algorithm works page-by-page, identifying the tables and extracting them. The extraction per se is not expensive - it's the identification that's time-consuming.

The reason the package - and the underlying Tabula Java library - exists at all is because there is no internal representation of a "table" in the PDF specification, unlike in say HTML or docx. Tables in a PDF are just arrangements of glyphs in something that looks to the human eye like a table. Thus there's no way to quickly query for the presence of a table or a list of all tables as no such list exists in the file.

So short, disappointing answer: nope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Thomas! Appreciate it.